# Using AdSense on Wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress.com, google-adsense

I have a blog that I host on the free `wordpress.com` service.

**Can I put AdSense ads somewhere on the blog?**

I realised, that scripts are not accepted in the posts or the Text widget.
I know that there is AdSense Manager plugin, but it's work if I would host my Wordpress blog somewhere. But I host the blog on the free service as `xxxx.wordpress.com`, and I don't have so much control over my plugins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you are not permitted to do that on Wordpress.com blogs.

> AdSense, Yahoo, Chitika, TextLinkAds, and other third-party advertising is not allowed here at WordPress.com. If you would like to run ads on your blog, one of these options may work for you:
>
> We have a feature called WordAds that lets WordPress.com bloggers with moderate to high traffic and appropriate content turn on ads and earn money from their blogs.
> You can run any ads you’d like if you manage your own WordPress installation. More info, including hosting recommendations, can be found at get.wp.com.
> WordPress.com VIP sites are permitted to run ads.
>
> In addition to AdSense-type ads, please do not use the following services on your blog:
>
> Sponsored or paid posts, including PayPerPost, ReviewMe, and Smorty.
> Affiliate or referral links to the following domains: usercash, clickbank, clickhop, cashrocks, payingcash.
> Clicktrackers and any promotions of the “I made a million on the internet and so can you” type of advertising (i.e. MLM, network marketing, cash gifting, etc.).
> Paid or sponsored post content is also prohibited.

[Source](http://en.support.wordpress.com/advertising/).